# Wrap a Table in a div Then appened a new div

Tags: jquery

How do i Wrap a table in a div?

I'm using $("table").each(function() to locate the tables i then need to enclose it in a div this is a snippet of my code tNum is just a sequential number to give the div a unique id

```
     var strToAppend = "<div>Blah Blah</div>
     $(this).wrap(function(){
       return "<div class = 'tabDiv'  id='tabDiv' + tNum +">" + $(this) + "</div>" +   strToAppend;
   });
```

this crates   [object Object]  before the table but no strToAppend

[object Object] is seen in the web page
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your aims could be achieved with the following, which perhaps looks more complex than your append a string, but is still quite simple:

```
$('table').each(
    function(i){
        var that = $(this),
            tabDiv = $('<div />',
                       {'class' : 'tabDiv',
                        'id' : 'tabDiv' + i}),
            newDiv = $('<div />').text('some text in a div element');
        that.wrap(tabDiv);
        that.parent().append(newDiv);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sCwp4/1/).

References:

- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#yourtableid').wrap('<div class="tabDiv">');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var strToAppend = "<div>Blah Blah</div>";  


   $("table").each(function(){

    $(this).wrap('<div class="wrapper_div" />');
    $(this).parent('.wrapper_div').prepend(strToAppend);

    });
```